Counter value is not saved Kotlin Decompose
I am studying Arkady Ivanov's Decompose library, but when changing the counter and changing the screen, the counter does not save its value and is reset to zero.
Interface of Component
interface SecondComponent {
    val model: Value<Model>

    fun onIncrementClicked()
    fun onDecrementClicked()
    fun onBackClicked()

    data class Model(
       val count: Int = 0
    )
}

Interface implementation
class DefaultSecondComponent(
    private val componentContext: ComponentContext,
    private val onBack: () -> Unit,
): SecondComponent, ComponentContext by componentContext{
     private val state = MutableValue(Model())
     override val model: Value<Model> = state

     override fun onIncrementClicked() {
         state.update { it.copy(count = it.count + 1)}
     }

     override fun onDecrementClicked() {
        state.update { it.copy(count = it.count - 1) }
     }

     override fun onBackClicked() {
        onBack()
     }
}

Creating navigation via ChildStack
private fun secondComponent(component: ComponentContext): 
    SecondComponent =
         DefaultSecondComponent(
            componentContext = component,
            onBack = navigation::pop
         )

I tried changing the lambda expression to update the variable

You need to save and restore the value manually using StateKeeper. The easiest way is to setup kotlinx-serialization library in your Gradle module and annotate your Model class with @Serializable annotation. Then the following code should help.
class DefaultSecondComponent(
    private val componentContext: ComponentContext,
    private val onBack: () -> Unit,
): SecondComponent, ComponentContext by componentContext{
    private val state = MutableValue(stateKeeper.consume(KEY_SAVED_STATE, Model.serializer()) ?: Model())
    override val model: Value<Model> = state

    init {
        stateKeeper.register(KEY_SAVED_STATE, Model.serializer()) { state.value }
    }

    override fun onIncrementClicked() { /*...*/ }
    override fun onDecrementClicked() { /*...*/ }
    override fun onBackClicked() { /*...*/ }

    private companion object {
        private const val KEY_SAVED_STATE = "SAVED_STATE"
    }
}

You can also check the related docs and sample.

Was surprised to see a reply from you, thanks for the great work in the form of Decompose and Essenty
